# MessageTarget giving No annotated methods were found error for annotation @PactVerifyProvider

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, pact, pact-jvm

I am trying to write provider test for kafka communications. I am using Pact-JVM with gradle dependency `group:'au.com.dius.pact.provider', name: 'spring', version: '4.1.41'` and plugin `au.com.dius.pact.gradle.plugin:4.1.41` with JUnit4 for jdk8 framework.

I am getting error '**No annotated methods were found interaction 'Valid message'. You need to provide a method annotated with @PactVerifyProvider("Valid message") on the classpath that returns the message contents.**' while running the provider test. My provider test has the same annotated method already present as suggested in the error message.

Below is my provider test:

```
package consumer.order;

@Provider("order-service")
@Consumer("accounts")
@PactFolder("src/contractTest/resources/pacts/")
@RunWith(PactRunner.class)
public class PublishOrderDetailsTest{

@TestTarget
public final Target target = new MessageTarget(Collections.singletonList("consumer.order.*"));

@Before
public void before(){}

@State("Publish order details")
public void publishOrderDetails(){}

@PactVerifyProvider("Valid message")
public MessageAndMetadata verifyOrderDetailsPubished(){
OrderDetials orderDetails = new OrderDetails("id123", "$200.00", "2024-03-12", "newyork", washington");
Map<String, Object> metaData = new HashMap<>();
metaData.put("contentType", "application/json");
metaData.put("topic", "order-details");

JsonSerializer<OrderDetials> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>();
return new MessageAndMetadata(serializer.serialize("order-details", orderDetails), metaData);
}
}
```

All values are matched as provided in the pact. InteractionRunner of pact is able to get the details from Pact files and also the details of method under @PactVerifyProvider annotation is getting picked through reflection but the run is, somehow, giving error '**No annotated methods were found for interaction 'Valid message'**'.

I am stuck at this error and I am new to pact. Can someone please suggest how to fix this issue?